# How do I check if an integer is within multiple ranges in c#?

Tags: c#

how do I check if a specific integer is within a specific range?

What I mean is if int total is between 20 and 39 (30) it doesn't go to 0-19 neither 40-69

Comment: `if (20 <= total && total <= 39)` ?  Are you just asking how to compare numbers?

Comment: Use comparison operators such as `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`. Don't use `Enumerable.Range(20, 30).Contains(n)`.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Do you not know how to compare two numbers? do you not know how to check if a number is in a bounded range? Is it checking against multiple ranges that is giving you problems? Do you think you're doing it right but its giving the wrong results? You need to be more specific about what your problem is. And also show us the code you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (total >= 20 && total <= 39) {
    //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend answering questions that have numerous duplicates. These questions should just be closed.

Comment: I've tried to stack my plans with that method and it just ignored the ifs even with an else